# Python script to transpose certain column's values into separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, function, data-cleaning

I have this data frame

| customer_id | customer_location | customer_contact_id | customer_contact_location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ES | 10 | DE |
| 1 | ES | 11 | DE |
| 1 | ES | 12 | FR |
| 2 | FR | 20 | GB |
| 3 | ES | 87 | ES |
| 3 | ES | 88 | ES |

I need to transpose it in a way so there is one row per customer_id. Like this.

| customer_id | customer_location | customer_contact_id1 | customer_contact_id2 | customer_contact_id3 | customer_contact_location1 | customer_contact_location2 | customer_contact_location3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ES | 10 | 11 | 12 | DE | DE | FR |
| 2 | FR | 20 |  |  | GB |  |  |
| 3 | ES | 87 | 88 |  | ES | ES |  |

So to outline what the python script should do.

1. Take the first data frame as input.
2. Transpose the contact level data (customer_contact_id and customer_contact_location) so that there is one row per customer_id.
3. Whatever the maximum amount of customer_contact_id's per any particular customer_id in the entire dataframe should be the number of columns created per each contact level attribute. In this example the maximum number is 3, so therefore there are 3 customer_contact id columns and 3 customer contact location columns.
4. The script should be dynamic so the user can define the columns by position that should not be transposed and those that should. E.g. If I add a new customer attribute (e.g. customer_postal_code) or a new customer_contact attribute that needs to be transposed (e.g. customer_contact_name), there should be parameters where those columns could be added.

## customer level columns

`customer_cols = ['customer_id', 'customer_location']`

## contact level columns

`contact_cols = ['customer_contact_id', 'customer_contact_location']`

## Number of columns to be created for each contact attribute

`max_contact_ids = rows.groupby('customer_id').size().max()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Kristina. I was looking for a question but I didn't found any. Please try to better explain your issue. Are you looking for someone to write code for you? If so, StackOverflow might not be the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard() # Your data here

customer_cols = ['customer_id', 'customer_location']
contact_cols = ['customer_contact_id', 'customer_contact_location']

# First create a new dummy index, then pivot
out = df.assign(
    new_cols=df.groupby("customer_id").cumcount().add(1)
).pivot(
    index=customer_cols,
    columns="new_cols",
    values=contact_cols
)

# Finally, fix the indices to your format:
out = out.set_axis(
    out.columns.map("%s%d".__mod__),
    axis=1
).reset_index()
```

out:

```
   customer_id customer_location customer_contact_id1 customer_contact_id2  \
0            1                ES                   10                   11   
1            2                FR                   20                  NaN   
2            3                ES                   87                   88   

  customer_contact_id3 customer_contact_location1 customer_contact_location2  \
0                   12                         DE                         DE   
1                  NaN                         GB                        NaN   
2                  NaN                         ES                         ES   

  customer_contact_location3  
0                         FR  
1                        NaN  
2                        NaN  

[3 rows x 8 columns]
```